# How can I compress multiple lines of code into 1 line of code?

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I have **many** similar block of code like this  :

```
        imgLoader({
            img: $chImage,
            btn: $btnAssignment,
            imgPath: basePath + '04-Section Exercise/Assignment.png'
        });
```

I want to compress them into **1** line.

```
imgLoader({ img: $chImage, btn: $btnAssignment, imgPath: basePath + '04-Section Exercise/Assignment.png' });
```

---

I did this one manually, and it takes me about **10** seconds. 
Imagine doing 100 of these is clearly not fun. 
I'm wondering if there is any Sublime Text 3 package/ plug-in that can help me do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turn out that in Sublime Text, we can accomplish this such task, but just highlighting the texts, and press :

## - Mac OS X : <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>j</kbd>

## - Windows : <kbd>ctr</kbd> + <kbd>j</kbd>

**Note:** `This will work only one way.`

Answer (score 2):

Sublime text has updated the shortcut, and it is now:

## - Mac OS X : <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>j</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Try using "find and replace" (ALT + CMD + F on Mac OSX)

Find: `,\\n` and replace with: `,` then `{\\n` with `{` etc...

Also, a more complex Regex could do it in one go.

Comment: What're talking about ? find it where ? Why do I need to do that ? I got none of that in my file. Can you be more specific on that ?

Comment: try `alt  + cmd + f` on mac you should get the "find replace" window, then enter a regex string there that will help you compress the multiple lines into one line

Comment: about the strings I wrote about `,\\n`, this is a regex string where `\\n` is a newline escaped with another \ for the regex string. the `,` before is is to match a `,` before a newline. this is an example regex string you could use. a more complex one would fit to do it in one go

Comment: Thanks for sharing your option, but I will stick with : `cmd + j`

Answer (score 0):

In Sublime Text:
Edit Menu --> Line --> Join Lines.

Shortcut for doing the above in Mac is : <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>j</kbd>

Windows Shortcut : <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>j</kbd>